# How to do ordinal logistic regression (OLR) on survey data with categorical answers?

Tags: r, categorical-data, survey, ordered-logit, polr

I am trying to learn how to use r to perform an ordinal logistic regression, in order to look for correlation between survey questions with categorical answers and another question asking about level of confidence.

I am very new to this, so I would really appreciate any help so that I can understand how to do this correctly. Here is my code to extract the survey responses from a .csv file and make them into factors, then to run the model:

```r
conf_levels <- c("Mycket stort", "Ganska stort", "Inte särskilt stort", "Inget alls")
cc_worry_levels <- c("1: Inte alls orolig", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10: Väldigt orolig")
pol_levels <- c("Instämmer helt", "Instämmer huvudsakligen", "Instämmer huvudsakligen inte")
sex_levels <- c("Kvinna", "Man", "Icke-binär")
infl_levels <- c("Mycket stort inflytande", "Ganska stort inflytande", "Litet inflytande")

M_dat3 <- M_dat %>% 
  dplyr::select(1, 59, 86, 10, 73, 52) %>% 
  mutate(AC_conf =  factor(X14d, levels = conf_levels)) %>% 
  mutate(CC_worry = factor(X21a, levels = cc_worry_levels)) %>% 
  mutate(pol = factor(X13h, levels = pol_levels)) %>% 
  mutate(sex = factor(X5, levels = sex_levels)) %>% 
  mutate(infl = factor(X18c, levels = infl_levels))
  
m <- polr(AC_conf ~  CC_worry + pol + sex + infl, data = M_dat3, Hess=TRUE)

ctable <- coef(summary(m))

p <- pnorm(abs(ctable[, "t value"]), lower.tail = FALSE) * 2

(ctable <- cbind(ctable, "p value" = p))
```

I then get the following warning message (which I do not understand):

```
Warning message:
In polr(AC_conf ~ CC_worry + pol + sex + infl, data = M_dat3, Hess = TRUE) :
  design appears to be rank-deficient, so dropping some coefs
```

And this output:

```
                                      Value Std. Error    t value       p value
CC_worry2                        24.6311742  2.0687289 11.9064295  1.095694e-32
CC_worry3                        19.7021684  1.7270242 11.4081600  3.806972e-30
CC_worry5                        20.4673985  0.8801048 23.2556373 1.247464e-119
CC_worry6                        19.7466790  1.0450020 18.8963065  1.223215e-79
CC_worry7                        18.3371264  0.9931632 18.4633565  4.072300e-76
CC_worry8                        19.0915938  0.7664600 24.9087942 5.974652e-137
CC_worry9                        19.0753845  0.8396835 22.7173506 3.018750e-114
CC_worry10: Väldigt orolig       18.8678001  0.5643129 33.4349945 4.253030e-245
polInstämmer huvudsakligen       -0.0770514  0.5740080 -0.1342340  8.932175e-01
polInstämmer huvudsakligen inte   0.1363698  0.9431398  0.1445913  8.850336e-01
sexMan                           -0.4852808  0.5830296 -0.8323434  4.052151e-01
sexIcke-binär                     2.8706326  2.1272160  1.3494787  1.771833e-01
inflGanska stort inflytande       1.7455581  1.2145067  1.4372568  1.506450e-01
inflLitet inflytande              2.3363109  1.2635429  1.8490159  6.445552e-02
Mycket stort|Ganska stort        20.0629038  1.1448351 17.5247104  9.281299e-69
Ganska stort|Inte särskilt stort 22.8893452  1.1789329 19.4153087  5.729075e-84
Inte särskilt stort|Inget alls   25.6752159  1.5726172 16.3264242  6.402883e-60
```

I'm not sure if I have the data in the right format, if I am running the model correctly, and then how to interpret the output. If anybody could make any suggestions, it would be much appreciated.

I am happy to create a reproducible example if that would be useful.